# Different bound properties on ComboBox

Tags: .net, wpf

I Have a ComboBox and I would like to bind to two different properties, one in the ComboBox and one in the ListBox. The properties are named Summary and Description. How can I accomplish this?

I Currently have this

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Summary"
            DisplayListMemberPath="???"
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered this is another thread,

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995853/how-to-display-a-different-value-for-dropdown-list-values-selected-item-in-a-wpf/3996627#3996627)