# How to display a different value for dropdown list and selected item in a CheckComboBox in Xceed WPF toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a CheckComboBox bound to a list consisting of one simple index and a full description like this:

```
code   full_description
1      Bus
2      Car
3      Motobike
```

Is it possible to show just 1,2,3 for selected items and show full description when dropping down the list?
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995853/how-to-display-a-different-value-for-dropdown-list-values-selected-item-in-a-wpf). But since CheckComboBox using the difference implementation, I have modified the part of `class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector` as follows:

```
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {   
        SelectorItem selectorItem = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualParent<SelectorItem>(container);

        if (selectorItem != null)
        {
            return DropDownTemplate;
        }
        return SelectedTemplate;
    }
```

It works fine with dropdown list, but no luck with selected items. I tried to dig into the source code of CheckComboBox but got nothing. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to just set the `ContentTemplate` of `ItemContainerStyle`?

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--Not sure what TargetType you should use-->
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--Here goes your DropDownTemplate-->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Also, set `DisplayMemberPath` to your desired property.

Answer (score 0):

1.override `ToString()` in your item class:

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
    return  full_description;
 }
```

2.set `DisplayMemberPath` to `code`

```
<CheckComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}"  
              DisplayMemberPath="code" />
```