# WPF ComboBox ItemTemplateSelector.Selecttemplate is never called

Tags: wpf, templates, combobox

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996627/7571171) I tried to use the following code to achieve a `ComboBox` with different templates depending on whether or not the drop down is open.
The `ComboBox` definition looks like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Id"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="Abbreviation" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownTemplate">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneTime}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                                   Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=DisplayMemberPath}" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                                   Text="Abbreviation" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>

        <infrastructure:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector"
                                                 DropDownDataTemplate="{StaticResource DropDownTemplate}"
                                                 SelectedDataTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

and the `ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector` looks like this:

```
public class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DropDownDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SelectedDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return DependencyObjectHelper.GetVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>(container) != null ? this.DropDownDataTemplate : this.SelectedDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that somehow **`SelectTemplate` is never called**, even although I checked all the `DynamicResource`s and `StaticResource`s.

Comment: Don't set DisplayMemberPath. And assign an instance of ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector to the ComboBox's ItemTemplateSelector property.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the edit on my answer. Just out of curiosity, why did you remove the part mentioning that it's basically only what you have already said? I just wanted to give you the credits for that, it was not meant to be bad or anything.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think doing so is necessary. IMO questions and answer should only contain essential content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the `ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector` to the `ComboBox` like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector}">
```

and you cannot set the `DisplayMemberPath` or the `SelectTemplate` method will never be called.