# WPF ComboBox bound with object list and display less different value in selected item than in the item list

Tags: c#, wpf, list, data-binding, combobox

I have this ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding imageFormats}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Extension}" />
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=" - " />
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Which is bound to this list:
`private List<ImageFormatModel> imageFormats = new List<ImageFormatModel>();`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ComboBoxImages.ItemsSource = imageFormats;
}
```

The Object `ImageFormatModel` consists of two strings:

```
public class ImageFormatModel
{
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Is possible that the selected item shows only the extension but in the dropdown menu both are shown?

Both values should be shown in this menu:

[image: Dropdown Menu]

But if I select one, only the extension should be visible. Not like this:
[image]

Comment: Change the data template?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995853/how-to-display-a-different-value-for-dropdown-list-values-selected-item-in-a-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` to the `TextBlock` elements to be hidden:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="tbStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DockPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Extension}" />
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=" - " Style="{StaticResource tbStyle}" />
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource tbStyle}" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```